# How to pass multiple file in Response.AppendHeader()

Tags: c#, .net, http

How can I pass multiple file in `appendheader()`
for single file my code is -

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sheet + ".pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: That's impossible. You can only send one file at a time to the browser

Comment: so,do i need to write same code on different page to send another file to browser?

Comment: You can only make your page send ONE file per response. If you'd like to send another file, you'll have to make another request that will be followed up by a response.

Comment: Or zip multiple files in one archive and send it instead